# ActionLink with anchor doesnt seem to work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, anchor, actionlink

I have this code in my layout.cshtml file:

```
<li>
     @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", "http", "localhost", "body-top", null, null)
</li>
<li>
     <a href="http://localhost:43854/#about">About</a>
</li>
```

which creates this mark-up:

```
<li><a href="http://localhost:43854/#body-top">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="http://localhost:43854/#about">About</a></li>
```

What makes me crazy is that , when i am not in my index action HOME does NOT work while about link works. I mean that when i click the home button nothing happens but when i click the about , the page loads.

while i am on the index action of home controller (it is an onepage template), the anhors both work...

**ADDITIONAL INFO #1**

The one page template is this: [METRONIC](http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/templates/frontend/onepage-index.html) You can view the various JS that it loads..In this page the anchors are just # bookmarks. I want to be able to link back to this page from "external" pages (other actions/controllers).

Comment: Are you sure that on other pages output markup is the same?

Comment: Yes. the second code bloxk is copied from the view-source command of chrome. the template is using jquery scroll and jquery migrate to move around the main page....I am not getting any errors in developer tools though....

Comment: If the generated code is the same in both instances, then this has nothing to do with the code you've actually posted. Instead, it seems like a problem with whatever you're using to provide the single-page experience. Post *that* code.

Comment: In regard to **ADDITIONAL INFO #1**: But, that code works, specifically clicking "Home" after having clicked one of the other links actually takes you back to their home view. That means, the problem is in *your adaption of their code*, which you haven't provided.

Comment: You will probably want to provide `null` to the protocol and hostname so the default values are generated. `@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, null, "body-top", null, null)`